# How do I change the primary URL of my Google Sites website?

Tags: redirect, google-sites

I have a Google site that is accessed using Google site's usual URL for sites they host: `http://sites.google.com/site/<sitename>`. I recently purchased a domain name for myself, and I set a subdomain of this new domain to point to my website hosted at Google Sites (`sitename.mydomain.com`). Unfortunately, Google and all the other search engines still point to pages at the old URL. Is there a way for me to make these search engines point to the new URL instead? Or alternately, is there a way to redirect users who visit the site at the old URL to the new one?

Comment: Did you follow [these steps](http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99448)? And remember that it might take upto 24 hours before your domain points to your Google site.

Comment: @Jacobvdb I already did that. What I want to do now is change my site's PRIMARY url, or add a redirect so that people actually see the new domain.

Comment: is it a normal gmail account or is it a apps account?

Answer (score 2):

*More* ->
 
*Manage Site*->
From the left menu pick *web address*
On this page you will find
`http://sites.google.com/site/mygsite` and 
**Add web address**
Here you put your domain `www.domain.com`

Now where you registered your domain (www.domain.com) you will have to add a CNAME entry, 
which should look something like this.

name                      Type               Data 
www.domain.com   CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com
**or**
Host                     Type                     Content
www                    CNAME       ghs.googlehosted.com

Like this you get your domain mapped and like this long sites url does not show up anymore.

Now if you have another Gsite within your gmail account
 
`http://sites.google.com/site/my2ndgsite`
Which you want to add with the following mapping `mysite.domain.com` to your domain.

You need to add the Web Address to your Gsite just like above. 
And where you have your domain registered you have to create another entry something like this

name                        Type               Data 
mysite.domain.com   CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com
**or**
Host                       Type                     Content
mysite                    CNAME       ghs.googlehosted.com

After this you will have to inform in the Google site that they can verify your domain mapping. 
And after that you will have to wait some time (24h) before actual mapping takes place.

**Note I** 
There used to be some domain registries that required a point (`.`) at the end of the ghs.googlehosted.com so it would be like this `ghs.googlehosted.com.`
**Note II**
Before the hosted domain used to be like this `ghs.google.com`. I am not 100% sure if that is not used anymore.

Comment: That's nice, but it's not what I was asking. As I've said, I already have my domain set up, I just need a way to make search engines and users use the new URL instead of the old one.

Comment: Create a second site in your gmail account with the mapping and leave the old long url with a different landing page where you leave a message with a link to your new domain url. You can try to insert an iframe with such a tag, though I never tried that!

Comment: The problem with that is that it doesn't preserve my raking in Google's (and other search engines) search results. I guess that might be the only way though.

Comment: @Jacobvdb can you help me with this? I did all the steps but when I go to my custom url (https://www.infinitymundi.it/) it works but the browser changes the custom url to the google site url (https://sites.google.com/view/something)

Answer (score 0):

You could leave a page with a meta refresh at the old url pointing to the new one?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Refresh_Meta_tag_and_HTTP_refresh_header

Comment: Hmm, maybe. I don't think Google Sites lets me put tags in the head section of the document though. I wonder what would happen if I put it in the body?